# Android application configuration

Tags: android, configuration

Where should I store my Android application's configuration settings?

Coming from the .NET world I was expecting something like a .config file. Do I create a file under res/values, and use that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no `res/assets`. There are `assets/` and `res/raw/` for arbitrary files, and `res/xml/` for arbitrary XML files. However, all of those are packaged as part of the APK and are not modifiable at runtime.

Take a look at [`SharedPreferences`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and the [`PreferenceScreen`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceScreen.html) system for collecting them from users, if these are user-selected configuration settings.

Comment: SharedPreferences is what I need. Thank you!